# Integrating Sagepay recurring payment with ASP.NET

Tags: opayo

I have completed Sagepay server protocol integration with ASP.NET Webforms for normal payment. But how does recurring payment works in Sagepay, any type of request/response format will be also useful.

Comment: Did you read the documentation available in the SagePay Developer Zone?

Comment: Yes, according to documentation AccountType is need to be set as C. They call it, Continuous Authority. But how time period need to be specified like month,quarterly etc. There isn't much information regarding the flow of recurring payment.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to set the CA payment frequency using Sage Pay. You will need to manage this yourself.